# How to use the continuous line segment algorithm (CSLA) method to substract baseline in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, baseline

Help me, I am try to convert CSLA method from R to Python from this paper "*DOI 10.1186/s12953-016-0107-*" and R code available at "https://github.com/tystan/clsa".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I try to convert one by one code in R to Python but even when I tried run R code it still not working. You can try this additional file "https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1186%2Fs12953-016-0107-8/MediaObjects/12953_2016_107_MOESM5_ESM.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I have solved my problem.